# Active button depending on the completed field

Tags: java, android

Field name

`AutoCompleteTextView etServices;`

What is wrong with the code below?

```
<Button
    android:enabled="@{!etServices.getText().toString().trim().equals(&quot;&quot;)}"
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:text="@string/Add" />
```

The problem is with `enabled`

Error:

`W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4) com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream`

Comment: What problem are you experiencing? what error do you get?

Comment: @CocoNess `W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream`